# How to stop windows from putting drop shadow on desktop icon text?

Tags: windows-10, user-interface

[This article](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-remove-drop-shadow-from-desktop-icons-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Go%20into%20Advanced%20system%20settings,icon%20labels%20on%20the%20desktop.) shows you how to remove the drop shadow and it does work. But then something happens and windows decides to put the drop shadow back even though the setting is set:

[image]

Again it does remove the drop shadow when  you first change the setting and when the computer first starts but then it puts it back a few minutes after I start my computer. Something is putting it back. Is there a way to either make the drop shadow a little more gray or permanently remove it?

Comment: The setting works permanently on a machine that is working correctly. I turn off drop shadow on all my machines.  Try DISM / SFC and see if that works.  .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: If you have multiple user profiles, e.g., a personal and Administrator user, try changing, *via* Registry,  in both. It might also be in `C:\Users\Default`.

Comment: @John, looking guid so far. If you turn your comment into an answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting works permanently on a machine that is working correctly.
I turn off drop shadow on all my machines.

So try DISM / SFC and see if that works. DISM and SFC is a good initial step to repair small faults in a machine.

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. 
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup 
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth 
(4) SFC /SCANNOW 
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

This has worked for me.